# Generate an expandable error message when a file does not exist

Tags: errors, expl3, external-files

I would like to understand how to use the `expl3` command `\msg_expandable_error` (as used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575687/2288)) with `\IfFileExists` to get an expandable error message if some external file does not exist.

I deliberately need to use `\msg_expandable_error` since my editor `texstudio` recognizes it and prints the error message in a red font.

Furthermore, is there a latex2e counterpart for `\msg_expandable_error`?

---

### Update

The desired output of red-styled error message can be obtained by the last code in @egerg's answer, when checking the log file inside texstudio while using `\msg_expandable_error`.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure TeXstudio recognizes the message because it expandable and not because of something else?...

Comment: @gusbrs I made experiments before using the cited answer, and I found that the expandable versions of warning and error messages are styled differently by texstudio.

Comment: I really don't know TeXstudio well enough to say, but I'd be much surprised if this has anything to do with the expandability of the message function. Most likely, it parses the log based on some regular expressions like everybody else. In your experiments, did you try to use the exact same text, but with a regular message?

Comment: Besides, considering `\file_if_exist:nTF` is not expandable itself, I'd bet `\IfFileExists` is also not...

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, I am sure that the regular message command is printed normally without styled in a red font. I tried it myself, and you can check the discussion here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117475/discussion-between-phelype-oleinik-and-diaa if you are interested.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I haven't used any latex2e form yet. That's why I asked for an example.

Comment: it really makes no sense to use an expandable error form for a non expandable command. the chat you link to doesn't seem related to this question???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found out there that the expandable one gets me the desired output. I don't know why but that's what I came up with.

Comment: well if that's what you want to do (although obscuring your code just because of a quirk in one editor's log parsing is a bit strange) then what is the question. If you have already tested the expandable error then you must have an example of its use already?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The code in the cited answer there is complicated for me to digest, so I need a simplified example to check the existence of a file. Secondly, I would like to know if there is a similar approach with latex2e.

Comment: the 2e form is `\PackageError}{my package}{missing file}{some help} ` if you made an example using that and said what it is doing wrong perhaps it would be possible to answer your question, otherwise it is hard to guess

Comment: This is clearly a bug in TeXStudio: TeX issues an error and TeXStudio just reports a warning. Misusing `expl3` for “fixing” a bug of the front-end doesn't seem the better way to go. The same experiment on TeXmaker correctly reports error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\CheckIfFileExists}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{OK}{\PackageError{diaa}{File #1 does not exist}{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\CheckIfFileExists{plain}

\CheckIfFileExists{xuaysyeuersss}

\end{document}
```

If I compile it with TeXmaker, I get

[image]

If I compile it with TeXStudio, I get

[image]

The conclusion is that we're in presence of a bug in TeXStudio whereby an error message

```
! Package diaa Error: File xuaysyeuersss does not exist.

See the diaa package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.11 \CheckIfFileExists{xuaysyeuersss}
```

is parsed by TeXStudio as a warning.

You can misuse `expl3` for getting an error message with

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\CheckIfFileExists}[1]
 {
  \file_if_exist:nTF { #1 }
   {OK}
   {\msg_expandable_error:nnn { diaa } { not~exist } { #1 }}
 }
\msg_new:nnnn { diaa } { not~exist }
 {
  The~file~#1~does~not~exist
 }
 {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CheckIfFileExists{plain}

\CheckIfFileExists{xuaysyeuersss}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main issue is that the error message is pretty uninformative. It's much better to ask the maintainers of TeXStudio to be more careful with their log file parsing.

Comment: Considering your last code, if you click on the `Log File` tab of texstudio, you will get the output I need as shown here https://i.ibb.co/F0kds4T/image.png by styling the error message in red. Here is the output when using `\msg_error` https://i.ibb.co/9TSHJyD/image.png.